# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Say#hello

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Confused at what to do. Default rails install by the RailsInstaller.

started a new demo app. Using rails 3.2.14.

created a controller

```
rails generate controller Say hello goodbye
```

However whenever I navigate to the localhost it returns an execjs error.

So for

```
http://localhost:3000/say/hello
```

I received

```
 ExecJS::RuntimeError in Say#hello

Showing c:/work/demo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:


  (in c:/work/demo/app/assets/javascripts/say.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Demo</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>

Rails.root: c:/work/demo
```

I have tried searching for solutions but the only one I thought seemed applicable hasn't helped.

I added to my gemfile the below and did bundle update. No Success.

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

What should I do?

EDIT

gemfile.lock http://pastebin.com/hGPJpxLp

Comment: @rmagnum2002 added to pastebin

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35488/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18246324-execjsruntimeerror-in-sayhello

Answer (score 1):

Find ExecJS's `runtimes.rb` file.

`bundle show execjs`

Make a backup. Open the `runtimes.rb` and edit. Find the part that starts with the line `JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(`. On the line containing `:command => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U"`, - remove the `//U` only. Now in the line containing `:encoding => 'UTF-16LE' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE` - change `UTF-16LE` to `UTF-8` . Save changes. Result should be like:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
    :name        => "JScript",
    :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
    :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
    :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

restart rails s, problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use gem install node .
I don't know why this works but it works .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `gem 'therubyracer'` and `gem 'execjs'` under assets group then run `bundle install` , also you can try [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) instead of execjs

Comment: please read this in his question: `I added to my gemfile the below and did bundle update.`

Comment: i did , but maybe they not inside the assets block !, that happens with me before

Comment: yea, you are right, it's hard to say where these gems are placed in.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem, After the R&D I installed node.js (http://nodejs.org/download/) the problem become solved.

Answer (score 0):

adding the  gem gem 'execjs' did it for me.